# LinearLayout weight does not work in DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-layout-weight

I have a custom view which is basically simply to show some info for a transaction, this is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#a8d1ff"
    android:weightSum="8">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="6">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/leftPartRowOneRelativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/nzNumberImageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/transaction_view_leftupside_nz_test" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nzNumberTextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="18"
                android:textSize="40dp" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/productNumberImageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/transaction_view_leftdownside_product_test" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/trx_summary_LinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:weightSum="10"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#FF000000"
            android:id="@+id/palceHolder0" android:text="testRow0"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#FF000000"
            android:id="@+id/palceHolder1" android:text="testRow1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#FF000000"
            android:id="@+id/palceHolder2" android:text="testRow2"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This it what it looks like in Android Studio **preview**, and it did meet my expectation (left and right divide the full parent container with **ratio 2:6**):

[image: looks good]

Later, this view will be shown in a `DialogFragment`,
and this is the `onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)` for `DialogFragment`:

```
MyView mv = new MyView(getActivity().getBaseContext());
mv.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
return mv;
```

But now, the **weight of 2:6** seems **not** working any more in pop up `Dialog`:

[image: not good]

I'm using Android 6.

Can anyone help?

[edit0]:
I want the `Dialog` show as screen width, but half screen height, so I put this code in `MyDialogFragment`:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes();
    params.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    params.height = this.height;
    getDialog().getWindow().setAttributes((android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams) params);
    super.onResume();
}
```

that `this.height` is passed in by `bundle` which is the `screen height/2`.

Comment: Did you get this resolved?

Comment: Here's another link that would be of interest for anyone facing this problem in the future.  https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/android/android-dialogfragment-match-parent/   Use relativelayout instead of linearlayout

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use `match_parent` (or fixed sizes) everywhere when dealing with `layout_weight`. If you use `wrap_content` at some point, the layout will adjust its size to its children and ignore their weight values.

In your case, you are specifying a `wrap_content` when inflating the dialog view. That should be `match_parent` instead:

```
MyView mv = new MyView(getActivity().getBaseContext());
mv.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
return mv;
```

Also make sure that the dialog window itself has a fixed width or is `match_parent`.

Comment: I've set the `Match_Parent` as the code you pasted, but I will not set the same for `Dialog`, because I don't want the Dialog window occupy the full screen, I just want make it half screen height.      And I did the testing, the result is still the same.

Comment: @Shawn Can you set a fixed width/height (e.g. `300dp` or so) to the view? If that solves the weight problem, you may compute a matching size for the dialog at runtime and set that as its width/height.

Comment: I've tried `mv.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(900, 300));` as you suggested , but still the same

Comment: I got it, one place i missed to set as `Match_Parent`, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

add android:fillViewport="true" into LinearLayout

```
  <LinearLayout
        **android:fillViewport="true"**
        android:id="@+id/llAccept"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_m"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_m"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_m"
        android:orientation="vertical">
```